# Mostrar en mi vista el formato d-m-Y

Tags: laravel-8, vistas

Hola a todos estuve leyendo la doc de php y encontre que hay un metodo que me lo cambia pero no me sirve puesto que las fechas que me muestra mi vista estan dentro de un foreach por lo que las fechas van cambiando por cada tupla.

```
@foreach ($dictations as $dictation)

   <tr class="bg-white border-4 border-gray-200">

     <td class="px-3 py-2"> 
      @php
        $newDate = date("d/m/Y", strtotime($dictation->time));
        echo $newDate; 
      @endphp
     </td>
```

El tema es que usando ese metodo si me cambia el formato pero la misma fecha se refleja en todas la filas

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿En qué formato vienen de la base de datos?

Comment: de mi base de datos viene Y-m-d

Comment: ¿Cuál es la propiedad que te devuelve la fecha?

Comment: dices que la misma fecha se refleja en todas las filas pero en la imagen se ven fechas distintas o_O o estoy loco?

Answer (score 2):

Si no estoy equivocado usas laravel con blade, por lo que puedes utilizar el paquete carbon: [Carbon](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/)

Te quitará muchos dolores de cabeza para trabajar con las fechas.

En tu caso puedes usarlo:

```
{{ \Carbon\Carbon::parse($expenses->date)->format('j F, Y') }}
```

Como nota si es blade, no necesitas @php:

```
@foreach ($dictations as $dictation)

   <tr class="bg-white border-4 border-gray-200">

                <td class="px-3 py-2"> 
                   {{ \Carbon\Carbon::parse($dictation->time)->format('d/m/Y') }}
                </td>
```

Comment: Si estoy usando carbon, recien lo descargue. Me cambia el formato pero todas las fechas son iguales las que me trae. que podra ser ?

Comment: En la imagen que subiste eso no es cierto se ve que las fechas cambian por cada fila, estas seguro que la propiedd que tiene la fecha es $dictation->time ??

Comment: digo que puse este codigo                                                                         {{ \Carbon\Carbon::parse($dictation->time)->format('d/m/Y') }} y es ahi que la fecha de todas filas son iguales y no deberia ser asi deberian ser distinta como las de la foto

Comment: Es que no se entiende tu problema porque dices que todas las fechas son iguales, sin embargo en la captura que subiste todas las fechas son distintas. Puedes subir la captura de cómo se ve ahora?

Comment: O a qué te refieres con que son iguales?? iguales en qué??

Comment: las fechas que me traen son las mismas ! cada fila repite la misma fecha

Comment: acabo de encontrar la solucion mira es como me mandaste ese codigo {{ \Carbon\Carbon::parse($dictation->date)->format('d/m/Y')}} ese codigo puse direactamente en mi plantilla de blade y todo perfecto. muchas gracias !

Comment: me daba error por que en vez de poner $dictation->date habia puesto $dictation->time. Eso me paso x copy y paste y no leer el codigo.

Comment: Ya, por eso te preguntaba si estabas seguro de que la propiedad era time ;D. Que bueno que pudiste resolver. Si te sirvió marca esta respuesta como aceptada.

Comment: nose como se hace presione la bandera y se puso algo rojo ahora googleo y lo hago